# C Libgcrypt: Unable to check if number is prime using libgcrypt

Tags: c, linux, testing, primes, libgcrypt

I am using a libgcrypt function `gcry_prime_check` to test if the number `3` is a prime number. It turns out 3 is not a prime number according to my the function. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    gcry_mpi_t cript_prime;
    gcry_error_t err;
    char buffer[8] = {0};
    char number[8] = {0};


    printf("%s\n", gcry_check_version ( NULL ) );
    gcry_control( GCRYCTL_INIT_SECMEM, 16384, 0 );

    cript_prime = gcry_mpi_new(16);

    strcpy(number,"3");
    gcry_mpi_scan(&cript_prime,GCRYMPI_FMT_USG,number,sizeof(number),NULL);

    gcry_mpi_print(GCRYMPI_FMT_USG,buffer,sizeof(buffer),NULL,cript_prime);

    printf("The number tested is: %s\n",buffer);

    err = gcry_prime_check(cript_prime,4);

    if(err)
    {
        printf("%s\n",gcry_strerror(err));
    }

    gcry_mpi_release(cript_prime);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
1.4.4
The number tested is: 3
Number is not prime
```

Also, a link for a good tutorial on using libgcrypt would be a big bonus. Thanks

EDIT:

Alright, I managed to generate a prime number using `gcry_prime_generate` and copied the value into `number`. Turns out it failed the prime check. But when you directly the pass the mpi output from prime generate to the prime check function ... it passes!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Like most prime tests, it tests for divisibility by small prime values before moving onto more expensive tests. Unfortunately, if your prime is one of these values, it is reported as being *divisible* (by itself) - and therefore composite.

Since the focus of libgcrypt is cryptographic applications, such a small prime has no utility. It's sloppy though, and wouldn't take much to rectify.

Comment: But the manual http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Prime_002dNumber_002dGenerator-Subsystem-Architecture.html  for the prime number generation architecture states the following  `The standard sieve algorithm using the primes up to 4999 is used as a quick first check.`

Comment: Quite. So, I'd wager `4999` is declared composite, and `5003` is declared prime.

Comment: I tried 5003, still same result. Will keep trying till probably 9973

Answer (score 0):

This is the function prototype, it takes a `gcry_mpi_t` structure and an Integer.

```
gcry_error_t gcry_prime_check (gcry_mpi_t p, unsigned int flags)
```

`gcry_mpi_t` : This type represents an object to hold an MPI.

`gcry_mpi_t` structures can be allocated using the `gcry_mpi_new` function

And can be set using the `gcry_mpi_set` function.

Comment: hmmm what about the gcry_prime_check(...,**unsigned int flags**) There is no documentation on that. I have tried integers from 0 to 4. All give the same result.

Comment: mpi.h contains a struct definition

struct gcry_mpi{  
  int alloced;         /* Array size (# of allocated limbs). */
  int nlimbs;          /* Number of valid limbs. */
  int sign;        /* Indicates a negative number and is also used
            for opaque MPIs to store the length.  */
  unsigned int flags; /* Bit 0: Array to be allocated in secure memory space.*/
                      /* Bit 2: the limb is a pointer to some m_alloced data.*/
  mpi_limb_t *d;      /* Array with the limbs */
};`

It seems to only use bit 0 and bit 2, and only for memory management.

Comment: Tyrns out the unsigned int flags are not considered at all in the prime_check function definition